# Angular 15 Password Validation - prevent form submit until all conditions are true

Tags: angular, validation, passwords

I'm currently self-learning Angular (started with version 15), following watching a YouTube tutorial on creating a registration and login system.  All works fine with that, but I now want to make some changes and I'm unsure as to the best approach.

I want to enforce conditions on the password, to ensure only strong passwords are used.  I want the validation to appear on the page and also prevent the submit button from working until all the conditions are met.  I've put together a quick [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5cgmjd?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fregister%2Fregister.component.ts) example showing my code so far.  What I have works, in terms of validating what the input value is, but I'm unsure of how to prevent the submit button from being pressed.  I have looked into making the form dirty, but as I'm still quite new with Angular, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I don't want to validate on clicking the submit button, I want this to be done live on the page.

I'm sure there is a better way of achieving this, but don't know how to go about it.  How would I use the validation to mark the form as dirty - is this an acceptable method?  Is what I've put together acceptable (I know it works, but that doesn't mean it's written correctly).  Constructive criticism welcome - we all have to learn somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is Angular form validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

```js
password = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern(/(?=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])(?=[0-9]).{8,}/)
]);
```

Your submit button already has `[disabled]="registerForm.invalid"`. If an individual control is invalid, then the form will also be invalid.

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't realised that form validation was flexible enough - this works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @Mike, you can simplify by using single pattern validator with a proper regex, instead of having multiple pattern validators.